# How to test this method by JUnit & EasyMock?

Tags: spring-mvc, junit4, easymock

I have a

```
@Component
public class MyBean{

         @Autowired
         Bean1 bean1;

         @Autowired
         Bean2 bean2;

         public void create(Param param1, Param param2){
           SomeObject object =    bean2.getDesiredResult();
         }

}
```

where `Bean2.java` has `instance variables` which are `autowired`-

```
class Bean2{
    @Autowired
    Bean3 bean3;

    @Autowired
    Bean4 bean4;

    @Autowired
    Bean5 bean5;

    public Object getDesiredResult(){
        // some code which calls method on some beans which have autowired
        // beans, and this goes on and on further.
    }

}
```

I have to test this method,

```
create(Param param1, Param param2)
```

The major problem is I continue to get these exceptons:

> No qualifying bean of type
>   Could not autowire field

because I cannot manually `component-scan` all the packages as they are so large in number. There are around 3000 java packages in the project

```
<context:component-scan base-package
```

I am using `JUnit` & `EasyMock` frameworks.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing two things. You want to do a unit test with JUnit and EasyMock. This do not require Spring or any autowire. You will do the following:

```
// Record the mock
Bean2 mock = createMock(Bean2.class);
expect(mock.getDesiredResult()).andReturn(new SomeObject());
replay(mock);

// Configure the tested class
MyBean testSubject = new MyBean();
testSubject.setBean(mock);

// Test
testSubject.create(new Param1(), new Param2());

// Check the mock was called as expected
verify(mock);
```

For the package scanning. Which is unrelated with the testing from my point of view, the package scan can be recursive.